# Change "User" for a file at a particular path

Tags: python, shutil

```
import shutil

path = input("Absolute path of the file and folder  ")


shutil.chown(path, user="Dude")
```

The above program should have executed successfully rather than this , it is showing me this error:

```
Absolute path of the file and folder  E:\SQL\Sqlemployee.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-b801c061f956>", line 4, in <module>
    shutil.chown(path, user="Dude")

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 1053, in chown
    raise LookupError("no such user: {!r}".format(user))

LookupError: no such user: 'Dude'
```

There are already four user:
Administrator, HP , Guest , Dude

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running the code on a Windows command prompt.

`shutil.chown` is [available only on `Unix` machines.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.chown)